# Stored Procedure for Calculating hours from 16th of Every Month to 15 of every month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm in the process of writing a stored procedure (for SQL Server 2012) that is supposed to calculate the number of hours for our employee from 16-15th of every month.

I have the following database structure

[image: My Database Structure]

I have written a stored procedure to calculate the hours but I think I can only get the week start date to filter my condition. The stored procedure is returning me the wrong result because the weekly start date is not always the 16th.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetTotalHoursBetween16to15EveryMonth]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    BEGIN TRY

    DECLARE @SixteenthDate datetime2(7) = DATEADD(DAY, 15, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
    DECLARE @currentDate datetime2(7) = getDate()
    DECLARE @LastSixteenthDate datetime2(7) = DATEADD(DAY, 15, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)), 0))

    IF(@currentDate >= @SixteenthDate)
    BEGIN
         SELECT 
             (Sum(Day1Hours) + sum(Day2Hours) + Sum(Day3Hours) +
              sum(Day4Hours) + Sum(Day5Hours) + sum(Day6Hours) + Sum(Day7Hours)) AS Total
         FROM 
             dbo.TimeSheets
         WHERE 
             WeekStartDate BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @SixteenthDate), -1) AND @currentDate 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            (Sum(Day1Hours) + sum(Day2Hours) + Sum(Day3Hours) + 
             sum(Day4Hours) + Sum(Day5Hours) + sum(Day6Hours) + Sum(Day7Hours)) AS Total
        FROM 
           dbo.TimeSheets
        WHERE 
           WeekStartDate BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @LastSixteenthDate), -1) AND @currentDate
    END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       THROW
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as ASP.Net?

Comment: Side note: if you're using `DATETIME2(7)` (and this is a **good** thing!), then you should start using `SYSDATETIME()` instead of `GETDATE()` to get the same accuracy on your "current date" as on anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably just do it the simple way:

```
declare @today          date = convert(date,current_timestamp)
declare @prev_month_end date = dateadd( day   , -day(@today) , @today          )
declare @period_start   date = dateadd( day   , 16           , @prev_month_end ) -- 16th of THIS month
declare @period_end     date = dateadd( month , 1            , @period_start   ) -- 16th of NEXT month

select @period_start = dateadd(month, -1 , @period_start ) ,
       @period_end   = dateadd(month, -1 , @period_end   )
where day(@today) < 16

select total_hours = coalesce(sum(t.hours),0)
from (           select id = t.id , report_date = dateadd(day,0,t.WeekStartDate) , hours = t.Day1Hours from dbo.TimeSheets t
       union all select id = t.id , report_date = dateadd(day,1,t.WeekStartDate) , hours = t.Day2Hours from dbo.TimeSheets t
       union all select id = t.id , report_date = dateadd(day,2,t.WeekStartDate) , hours = t.Day3Hours from dbo.TimeSheets t
       union all select id = t.id , report_date = dateadd(day,3,t.WeekStartDate) , hours = t.Day4Hours from dbo.TimeSheets t
       union all select id = t.id , report_date = dateadd(day,4,t.WeekStartDate) , hours = t.Day5Hours from dbo.TimeSheets t
       union all select id = t.id , report_date = dateadd(day,5,t.WeekStartDate) , hours = t.Day6Hours from dbo.TimeSheets t
       union all select id = t.id , report_date = dateadd(day,6,t.WeekStartDate) , hours = t.Day7Hours from dbo.TimeSheets t
     ) t
where t.report_date >= @period_start
  and t.report_date <  @period_end
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I also need  to pass in date and get the payroll hours from that 16th to the date. for example if i want to find out how many hours an employee have worked from 16th to todays date(input param), i should be able to see that. let's say an employee have worked from 16th and he wants to see his current total hours he should be able to see it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Always start with start or an end of a month.

E.g. Here's some logic

**Start Date = Start date of previous month + 16**

**End Date = Start date of current month + 15**

Following might help you figure out the dates

```
-- First Day of the month
select DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate()), 0)

-- Last Day of previous month
select dateadd(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate()  ), 0))
```

More examples are [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3076421/Examples-of-how-to-Calculate-Different-SQL-Server-Dates.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Life is easier with a little data normalization.  Don't work from the spreadsheet-style table

```
CREATE VIEW Timesheets_Normalized AS
SELECT 
  [id]
 ,[Date] = DATEADD(day,[Date_Offset],[WeekStartDate])
 ,[Hours]
FROM MyTable a
UNPIVOT([Hours] FOR [Date_Column] IN (Day1Hours,Day2Hours,Day3Hours,Day4Hours,Day5Hours,Day6Hours,Day7Hours)) b
INNER JOIN (VALUES (0,'Day1Hours'),(1,'Day2Hours'),(2,'Day3Hours'),(3,'Day4Hours'),(4,'Day5Hours'),(5,'Day6Hours'),(6,'Day7Hours')) c([Date_Offset],[Date_Column])
  ON (b.[Date_Column] = c.[Date_Column])
```

Then you can get your answers very simply:

```
SELECT
  MIN([Date])  AS [PayrollMonthStart]
 ,MAX([Date])  AS [PayrollMonthEnd]
 ,SUM([Hours]) AS [TotalHours]
FROM Timesheets_Normalized
GROUP BY YEAR(DATEADD(day,-15,[Date])),MONTH(DATEADD(day,-15,[Date]))
HAVING CAST(GETDATE() AS date) BETWEEN MIN([Date]) AND MAX([Date])
```